# Como iniciar um chat com um usuário fora do contexto de uma pergunta

Tags: suporte, chat

Como eu faço pra iniciar um chat com um usuário fora do escopo de uma discussão em uma pergunta?

Eu sei que em casos de longas discussões em uma pergunta o sistema mesmo sugere (oferecendo a opção "let us continue...") e que é possível criar uma sala diretamente no chat e depois convidar o usuário para entrar nela. 
Mas não vi uma forma de iniciar um chat diretamente a partir da visualização do perfil de alguém.

É possível fazer isso? Se não, me parece que seria interessante ter essa opção no perfil. O que acham?

**Contexto do momento em que eu senti essa necessidade:**
[Eu estava ajudando um usuário com uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23462/algu%C3%A9m-saberia-alguma-fonte-de-pesquisa-confi%C3%A1vel-para-intelig%C3%AAncia-artificial), e discutindo a potencial abrangência via comentários. Eventualmente o usuário excluiu a pergunta indicando que submeteria outra com uma dúvida mais específica eventualmente. Porém, eu ainda tinha uma sugestão de referência de estudos que gostaria de compartilhar com ele. Pensei em fazer isso via chat, mas não achei opção no perfil dele e tampouco na pergunta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Em geral, a plataforma Stack Exchange não oferece meios de um usuário se comunicar com outro fora do contexto de uma pergunta, e isso se extende ao chat. Quando um usuário realmente precisa falar diretamente com outro (ex.: várias vezes precisei alertar um ou outro usuário novato que estava fazendo edições incorretas nas wikis de tag), ele acaba recorrendo ao "poor man's instant messaging" - que é comentar em *qualquer* publicação do outro, e um tempo depois apagar o comentário. (o que eu acho um saco, aliás...)

Não sei se seria prejudicial de alguma forma ter essa comunicação fora do contexto de uma pergunta/resposta. Por mim, podíamos tentar. Mas isso é a equipe do SE que decide...

P.S. Sugestão: mesmo **dentro** do contexto de uma pergunta, seria muito interessante ter, por exemplo, um *magic link* que convertesse algo como [continuar-chat] naquela ação padrão de criar uma sala, migrar os comentários pra lá (isso é feito? não me lembro...) e deixar um comentário automático convidando o outro usuário. Não resolveria o problema do OP, mas já daria uma ajuda...

Comment: Sim, os comentários são migrados. E concordo com a proposta do final, e acho que é fiel à proposta da plataforma (iniciar chat pelo perfil eu não gosto).

Comment: Também acho que faz mais sentido mesmo que todo chat seja feito no escopo de uma pergunta (afinal, o site exista pra perguntas e respostas). MAS, descobri que há uma forma de iniciar uma conversa no chat diretamente no perfil do usuário sem qualquer relação com perguntas: (1) acesse o chat via menu "bate-papo" abaixo; (2) clique em "users"; (3) procure pelo nome/ID do usuário; (4) clique em "start a new room with this user".

Comment: E também concordo com a sua sugestão! :) Ia ficar bem mais legal, principalmente se isso também pudesse ser feito nos comentários de uma pergunta excluída.

Comment: Podem sempre ir ao chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha e dai iniciar uma conversa privada.

Answer (score 11):

Lembrando que são necessários [20 pontos para participar no chat](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges):

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

## Se o usuário está presente em uma sala de chat

Clicar em cima do nome do usuário, abre-se a seguinte janela de diálogo e podemos selecionar a primeira das **Actions**: `stat a new room with this user`:

[image]

## Se o usuário já frequentou o chat

Há de se [procurar pelo seu perfil](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users?tab=all&sort=recent):

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

E ao abrir o perfil, selecionar <kbd>start a new room with this user</kbd>:

[image]

## Se o usuário nunca visitou uma sala de chat

Criar uma sala vazia no endereço http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new e fazer o convite em um comentário.

[image]

Comment: Nossa! Que usuário maneiro você escolheu para fazer o exemplo. \o/ vlw

Comment: Antigo Trem Doido, eu lembro :) Curto muito o Ledger também

Comment: Esse papel ficou muito foda! Um dos mais fodas personagens que já vi.

Comment: Tipo um [**libelo**](http://dicionariocriativo.com.br/wikipedia/libelo) do autor, digo, ator.  . . . . Achava que libelo significava outra coisa, mas taí, Joker pacas o link esse.

Comment: Concordo plenamente, @TiagoSilva. ;)