# Há um magic-link para iniciar o chat com um usuário específico?

Tags: suporte, status-recusado

Nos comentários de uma pergunta, é possível criar uma sala com um usuário em específico?

<kbd>+1 - **fulano**</kbd>
<kbd>Não concordo, nem discordo, porém ao contrário. - **dudu**</kbd>
<kbd>@dudu Isso é uma cilada! - **edu**</kbd>

No exemplo, supondo que @dudu queira prolongar a conversa com @edu no chat para evitar "ruído" nos comentários, existe algo parecido com `[chat:@edu]`?

Eu cheguei a ver [essa resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2175/4808) onde menciona criar um sala vazia e enviar o convite para o outro usuário. Essa é a única forma?

Comment: Isto seria muito útil.

Comment: Isto seria **mesmo** muito útil. A postagem já tem mais de um ano, e tem alguns votos positivos (nenhum negativo). Não seria justo ela ter ao menos algum feedback dos responsáveis pelo sistema a respeito da sugestão dada?

Comment: Eu estava pensando em desenvolver uma extensão com esse recurso, ia até sugerir pro Guilherme. Obrigado por *ressuscitar* esse tópico Luiz :D

Comment: Por nada Renan. Pena que ninguém mais relevante deu atenção. :/

Comment: Vocês sabem que se os comentários começam se prolongar o mecanismo já sugere ir para o chat, né?

Comment: @bigown Sim, sei. Só que as vezes você quer justamente evitar o prolongamento.

Answer (score 4):

Criar uma sala de chat com outra pessoa é algo que o sistema incentiva *caso a conversa se torne longa demais pros comentários*. Até lá, discussões em comentários podem ter valor continuando públicas e, caso se tornem obsoletas, podem ser limpas bem facilmente pelos moderadores.

Infelizmente, dar o poder de criar salas específicas - com um simples atalho - tem um potencial muito maior pra abuso ou desuso do que o justificável pelo problema que ela tenta resolver. Ser convidado pra um chat, por um usuário que você potencialmente não conhece, é algo que deve acontecer *depois* de você se mostrar investido na conversa, e não *antes* disso.

O SOpt é assíncrono por natureza, com alguns mecanismos síncronos disparados automaticamente, caso se mostre necessário ou proveitoso em alguma circunstância, como é o caso do chat automático em comentários longos. Até esse ponto, é difícil saber quando algo é realmente ruído. E permitir que alguém te convite pra um chat, à dispor do "convidador", não é exatamente algo que combina com o site.

Sempre existe o atalho `[chat]`, se quiser convidar pra sala padrão do SOpt. Ou a alternativa da [resposta do Brasofilo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2175), que faz tudo manualmente.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Gabe. :) Eu entendo essas motivações que você coloca. Mas permita-me colocar alguns contra-argumentos. 1) Há outros recursos existentes que se forem abusados também podem gerar esse mesmo tipo de problema. A solução utilizada para coibir os problemas é sempre a mesma fornecer o "direito" com base em reputação. Veja, por exemplo, o direito de comentar. Então, eu me pergunto: por que o direito de usar uma tag para iniciar uma sala de chat dos comentários não pode existir para usuários com reputação maior? Seria muitíssimo útil e reduziria muito esse problema apontado.

Comment: 2) O funcionamento automático do sistema **não é bom**. Primeiramente, é difícil prever esse comportamento. Na minha experiência, o sistema já me sugeriu isso inúmeras vezes, mas nunca quando eu realmente precisava. :/ Eu já uso o atalho `[chat]`, mas a ideia é diferente: eu gostaria mesmo, em algumas poucas ocasiões, de iniciar um chat diretamente, até mesmo com o autor de uma pergunta ou resposta, por exemplo.

Comment: Enfim, por mais que se diga que esse site não existe para se fazer chat, a funcionalidade existe e as pessoas usam. Tornar isso chato (*pun intended*) de utilizar não me parece a forma mais apropriada de coibir problemas, pois vocês apenas prejudicam quem realmente quer usar para o bem. P.S.: A resposta do Brasofilo é muito útil. Mas eu duvido que você tenha saco de ir lá no chat, abrir uma sala manualmente, e então voltar pra postar o link pro usuário. Eu não tenho.

Comment: Gabe, vir aqui para (1) meramente informar as regras subjetivas ("[...] não é exatamente algo que combina com o site [...]" é uma opinião sua - e até onde eu percebo, baseada apenas em suposições do que aconteceria, já que você não avaliou ou respondeu às minhas colocações) e (2) colocar [tag:status-recusado] na pergunta, **não é** um comportamento bacana para uma comunidade em que se espera trabalho conjunto e cooperativo. Sei que você é ocupado, mas quem não é? Ninguém mais deu atenção a esta postagem, mas a sua ausência é desmotivadora não só pra mim, mas para qualquer leitor futuro.

Comment: @LuizVieira Antes de responder ao post como recusado eu conversei com 2 outros CMs diferentes, em momentos diferentes. Eles leram o post, eu expliquei a ideia, apresentei os argumentos (caso a tradução automática não fosse muito clara). Nós debatemos a ideia, eles me contaram de outros casos de sugestões parecidas e porque não acreditamos que seja uma boa idea permitir que convites para chat sejam criados automaticamente.

Comment: @LuizVieira Eu entendo, e me preocupo muito, que do lado de vocês pareça que eu tomo as decisões sobre o site sozinho, e que sejam "opinião minha". Eu sou o único que dá as caras por aqui. Fazer o meio campo entre a comunidade internacional e uma empresa que não fala a língua de vocês tem *diversos* desafios, e esse é um deles. É difícil ser a única opinião "oficial" sobre algo e não parecer autoritário, mesmo que o processo por trás seja tão democrático quanto é possível.

Comment: Ok. Então, em primeiro lugar (e, por favor, não leve a mal este comentário), você mereceu o puxão de orelha porque não deixou claro todo esse processo na sua resposta. O AP, eu e os demais que votaram positivamente e favoritaram merecem a resposta completa.

Comment: Em segundo lugar (e se você me permite essa sugestão), em casos assim eu não veria mal se você (re)criasse a postagem no metão para que a discussão pudesse acontecer por lá (isto, claro, se alguma discussão similar já não existisse). Eu não sei o AP e os demais, mas eu tenho condições de argumentar o porquê eu acho isso importante também em inglês. Talvez até por aqui no Meta Pt pudesse ser feita em inglês mesmo. E dessa forma, você não corre o risco de parecer autoritário injustamente. :)

Comment: Aliás, o AP ou eu poderíamos já ter iniciado toda essa discussão lá no Metão ou aqui em inglês... só fizemos da forma atual porque a nossa comunidade é esta, não aquela. O "problema" dos níveis gerenciais não é necessariamente nosso problema, entende? Vcs CMs poderiam facilitar quando uma discussão esbarrar nesse item.

Comment: @LuizVieira Agradeço as duas sugestões. Eu costumo ser reticente em sair citando nomes porque não é assim que nós trabalhamos. Todos os CMs tem autoridade igual, e não precisamos descrever em detalhes o processo por trás de toda decisão sobre recurso. Mas isso é fácil de perceber no MSO/MSE, com vários CMs participando, que funcionam explicitamente como um time. Aqui, é mais complicado. Não é comum sairmos deferindo decisões à outros CMs nos nossos posts (A Bluefeet não escreve respostas dizendo "O Shog falou..."), mas talvez seja um caminho adequado aqui.

Comment: Por nada. Eu realmente espero que você não ache que eu esteja apenas sendo chato. Eu faço isso porque realmente acredito que vai ajudar.

Comment: @LuizVieira Levar a discussão pro MSE também não é algo que normalmente cabe aos CMs, e implementar aqui é uma faca de 2 gumes. Por um lado, pode aumentar o engajamento de quem *pode* debater em inglês. Por outro lado, pode diminuir o engajamento de quem *não pode* debater em inglês. A nossa solução é tentar fazer com que esse site tenha poder de influenciar recursos, tanto quanto o MSE tem, mas não com o mesmo volume e intensidade. É longe do ideal, mas parece ser a solução com menos potencial de más consequências.

Comment: @LuizVieira Quer mover a discussão pro chat? (acho que esse era seu plano desde o começo `:D`)

Comment: Honestamente prefiro que fique por aqui, pra facilitar a referência futura de outros (o chat, como você mesmo argumenta rs, não é o tipo ideal de ferramenta para certas coisas). Até porque esta discussão já acabou. Você explicou que a decisão não depende só de você. Eu entendi. Não estou satisfeito, mas entendi. :) Obrigado pelas respostas.

Comment: @LuizVieira Sem problema. Sinto muito pelo stress causado, e sinto mais ainda pelo fato de que nenhum dos nossos processos no site é ideal, e todos os que implementamos, ou pensamos em implementar, não resolvem os problemas de maneira sequer adequada. Uma comunidade, pra ser uma comunidade, precisa de atenção dos 2 lados (da plataforma, e dos usuários) e, infelizmente, os sites internacionais tem um gargalo muito pequeno, pra 2 funis muito grandes. Eu recebo os puxões de orelha de peito aberto, justamente por saber (melhor que ninguém) que as falhas existem.