# Opção para compartilhar conteúdo entre desenvolvedores dentro do Stack Overflow

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, status-recusado, divulgação

Um amigo e colega desenvolvedor acabou de realizar o cadastro dele no Stack Overflow e logo que se cadastrou foi procurar meu perfil e uma dúvida que tenho quanto ao Google Maps API do Android e logo assim encontrou uma pergunta com uma resposta satisfatória.

Quando foi compartilhar para mim, percebemos que por enquanto podemos compartilhar em redes sociais como Facebook, Twitter e outros, menos no próprio Stack Overflow. Em algumas empresas o acesso para redes sociais são bloqueadas. Logo em baixo de uma pergunta ou resposta tem um link <kbd>compartilhar</kbd> do lado do botão <kbd>editar</kbd>, porém mostra apenas o link, Google, Facebook e Twitter. Não seria interessante um ícone do Stack Overflow e quando a gente clicasse nele abrisse um modal mostrando uma busca de usuários do Stack Overflow ou até mesmos amigos que temos adicionados futuramente para a gente enviar o conteúdo para o mesmo?

Gostaria de saber se é possível futuramente implementar algum recurso que permita compartilhar determinado conteúdo aqui mesmo do Stack Overflow para um outro amigo que seja desenvolvedor. Acredito que possa entrar mais questões, como adicionar como amigo, conversas (como no caso do Facebook que determinado material pode ser compartilhado diretamente pelo chat), seguir desenvolvedor, entre outros.

Qual a opinião de vocês quanto a este assunto?

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1361/101 http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3825/101 http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3833/101

Comment: Obrigado pelos links @bigown

Comment: Giancarlo, fiz um update na resposta que pode lhe ser interessante.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pois é, vocês esbarraram em uma característica fundamental do site: as pessoas não interessam, interessam as perguntas e respostas.

O máximo que podem contar é a l[ista de favoritos de cada um](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/20555/giancarlo-giulian?tab=favorites), que é pública. Se quiser solicitar "funcionalidades de rede social", pode se preparar para fazer um estudo profundo e apresentar uma defesa sociológica muito bem fundamentada.

Foi exatamente daí que [nasceu o Stack Overflow](https://blog.codinghorror.com/introducing-stackoverflow-com/), da análise detalhada dos prós e contras de fórums, redes sociais, sites de suporte. A amizade e o compadrismo, tão naturais nas relações humanas, são explicitamente barrados aqui.

Para o que deseja fazer use seu blog, Facebook, Twitter ou semelhante.

Tudo bem, a trilogia ([Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), [Super User](https://superuser.com/)) está cheia de profissionais que precisam exatamente o que você está pedindo, e para isso a rede [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/) disponibiliza uma [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) e o acesso ao [Banco de Dados](https://data.stackexchange.com/) para que resolvamos o problema nós mesmos.

É só visitar o Stack Apps e encontrar uma app que satisfaça a necessidade, tipo: [Follow your friends on StackOverflow with FriendOverflow](https://stackapps.com/q/1863/10590). Se não, [faça a sua](https://stackapps.com/questions/4306/all-your-stack-posts).

Ou como bem lembra o JorgeB. também pode criar uma sala de chat. As salas são públicas, mas acho que com certeza quase ninguém vai ter interesse nos assuntos de vocês. Vide [Como iniciar um chat com um usuário fora do contexto de uma pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2175/201).

Comment: Ou podem sempre usar o chat do site para fazer isso...

Comment: positivo operante, adicionado à resposta ;)